# Python connect to Oracle database with TCPS

Tags: python, database, oracle, ssl, tcpserver

trying to connect Oracle database with TCPS connection from python but its failing with ORA-28759: failure to open file.

I am not sure what I need to be configured in wallet when connecting from local/other server to database on different server.

```
    import os
    import os.path
    import sys
    import cx_Oracle

    ORACLE_VERSION=19.3
    os.environ['ORACLE_BASE']=/Users/machild/Documents/oracle
    os.environ['ORACLE_HOME']='$ORACLE_BASE/product/instantclient/$ORACLE_VERSION'
    os.environ['DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH']='$ORACLE_HOME/lib'
    os.environ['OCI_DIR']='$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH'
    os.environ['TNS_ADMIN']='$ORACLE_BASE/network/admin'


    Connection_String ='username/password@(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCPS)(HOST=orclconsapp.vci.map.com)(PORT=1587)))(CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME=cons_app)))'

    connection = cx_Oracle.connect(Connection_String)


    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("""select to_char(sysdate,'mm/dd/yyyy') from dual""")
    for result in cursor:
        print(result)
```

```
**Its failing with below error**

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/machild/Documents/oracle_conn.py", line 16, in <module>
connection = cx_Oracle.connect(Connection_String)
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-28759: failure to open file


I think it would need a wallet but not sure what exactly goes in wallet if we want to connect from external server( not where database is running). Any ideas?
```

Comment: The wallet file location can be given in your sqlnet.ora file like `WALLET_LOCATION=(SOURCE = (METHOD = file) (METHOD_DATA = (DIRECTORY="/Users/xxx/Downloads/instantclient_19_8/network/admin")))`, or it can be in the [19c Easy Connect syntax](https://download.oracle.com/ocomdocs/global/Oracle-Net-19c-Easy-Connect-Plus.pdf), or in the tnsnames.ora file (examples of the last two are in the link). Regarding getting a wallet - ask your DBA.

Comment: Comments: Don't set ORACLE_BASE or ORACLE_HOME with Instant Client. There is no need to set TNS_ADMIN since you have set it to the default location. Beware that setting DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH is broken on macOS due to SIP. It's better to use [`init_oracle_client()`](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/initialization.html#using-cx-oracle-init-oracle-client-to-set-the-oracle-client-directory).  Finally, Instant Client 19.8 is available for macOS.  It has notarized DMGs, see https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/notarized-macos-oracle-instant-client-packages-make-installation-easier

Comment: For background info for future readers landing here: you no longer always need a wallet when connecting to Oracle cloud DBs.  With recent Oracle Client libraries you can use 1-way TLS.   See [Easy wallet-less connections to Oracle Autonomous Databases in Python](https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/post/easy-way-to-connect-python-applications-to-oracle-autonomous-databases).

Answer (score 3):

I experienced ORA-28759 also. I was using Python/SQLAlchemy to talk to an Oracle database requiring TCPS. My DBA gave me a trusted certificate, which I had to store in a wallet.

**tl;dr:** I created a wallet file using `okapi`, imported my certificate into that wallet, then edited `sqlnet.ora` to contain the location of the wallet. I used the `TNS_ADMIN` environment variable to point to `sqlnet.ora`. (Basically, what Christopher Jones suggests.) Since you've already got an existing `TNS_ADMIN`, you might want to just edit the `sqlnet.ora` in there to point to the wallet, after you've created it.

Below are the details for my situation, including how I created a wallet. What I did combines information from these sources:

1. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e40393/asoappf.htm#ASOAG9831
2. https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/dbseg/configuring-authentication.html#GUID-3EA07020-A9F3-4FF9-9518-E1AEA3BDDBBE
3. https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/initialization.html#optnetfiles

Note: the details that follows is based on Windows!

The first thing I had to do is create a new wallet. The first URL from docs.oracle.com describe the command that worked for me: `orapki`. This tool came from my local installation of Oracle XE 18c (Windows).

To create a wallet, I typed:

```
orapki wallet -nologo create -wallet C:\Users\rick\wallet -auto_login
```

This created a folder `C:\Users\rick\wallet` that contained four files: cwallet.sso, cwallet.sso.lck, ewallet.p12, ewallet.p12.lck. The cwallet.sso is the 'auto-login wallet', and the ewallet.p12 is the PKCS#12 wallet. (Further details are in the documentation.) NOTE: `-auto_login` creates a wallet that does not need a password to open, though I was prompted to enter a password. I made up a throw-away password, and did not need to use it again.

The Oracle database I was trying to connect to required my wallet to contain a trusted certificate. `orapki` has the `-trusted_cert` switch, which allowed me to import it into my wallet.

```
orapki wallet -nologo add -wallet \Users\rick\wallet -cert \Users\rick\oracle-ca.pem -trusted_cert
```

I was able to confirm that the wallet contained the certificate, using:

```
orapki wallet -nologo display -wallet \Users\rick\wallet -complete
```

My output:

```
C:\Users\rick>orapki wallet -nologo display -wallet \Users\rick\wallet -complete
Requested Certificates:
User Certificates:
Trusted Certificates:
Subject:        CN=Redacted,OU=Oracle,O=Amazon Web Services\, Inc.,ST=Washington,L=Seattle,C=US
Issuer:         CN=Redacted,OU=Oracle,O=Amazon Web Services\, Inc.,ST=Washington,L=Seattle,C=US
Serial Number:  AA:C7:REDACTED:AE:75
Key Length      1024
MD5 digest:     66:EC:REDACTED:9F:0D
SHA digest:     D4:0D:REDACTED:3C:50:91
```

To make use of this wallet, you have to point to it. This involved two steps for me. The first step was to create a `sqlnet.ora` file that pointed to the wallet. The second step was to set the `TNS_ADMIN` environment variable to the directory containing the `sqlnet.ora` file. In my case, both the `sqlnet.ora` and the wallet files were in the same directory.

The second URL from docs.oracle.com shows how to specify the wallet location (directory) inside of the `sqlnet.ora` file. My `sqlnet.ora` file contained:

```
SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (NTS)
NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH= (TNSNAMES, EZCONNECT)
WALLET_LOCATION=(SOURCE=(METHOD=FILE)(METHOD_DATA=(DIRECTORY=C:\Users\rick\wallet)))
SSL_CLIENT_AUTHENTICATION=FALSE
```

I obtained my `sqlnet.ora` from my Oracle server's network/admin directory. I copied this file into the same directory as my wallet, then I edited it. For good measure, I also copied the `tnsnames.ora` file from network/admin into the wallet directory, though I didn't need to edit this file.

Finally, the cx_Oracle documentation (the third URL) provides the last detail: how to point cx_Oracle to this wallet. From my understanding, you point cx_Oracle to the directory containing the `sqlnet.ora`, and `sqlnet.ora` points to the wallet directory.

The documentation says to use the `config_dir` named argument to `cx_Oracle.init_oracle_client()` to specify the location of the `sqlnet.ora` file, but since I was using SQLAlchemy I was not calling this directly. However, the documentation says by default the driver will look for the `sqlnet.ora` files in a few standard locations, including the directory specified by the `TNS_ADMIN` environment variable.

I set `TNS_ADMIN` using :

```
set TNS_ADMIN=C:\Users\rick\wallet
```

Then when I ran my Python program, it worked!

Comment: the steps you have listed above are great and work perfectly for me. unfortunately i am still not able to connect via sqlalchemy. Can you post the way you acquire a connection to Oracle with encryption using sqlalchemy in this link as an answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75011719/connect-to-oracle-on-an-encrypted-port-using-sqlalchemy?