# How to make a cx_oracle connection encrypted with TLS? Do I have to use Oracle Wallets?

Tags: python, oracle, tls1.2, wallet, tls1.3

Need to use cx_oracle module with python 3.x version to connect Oracle 19c with TLS. There are firewalls and proxies.

How to implement it?
Do I have to use Oracle Wallets?
Is TLS 1.2 good enough or I need TLS 1.3 in 2022?

```
import cx_Oracle
conn = cx_Oracle.connect("uname/pwd@//localhost:1521/sd")
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT 'Hello' FROM dual")
res = cur.fetchall()
```

Comment: See [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66094119/python-connect-to-oracle-database-with-tcps). Yes, you usually need a Wallet, and the server usually determines which TLS version you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is a cloud DB you no longer always need a wallet.  With recent Oracle Client libraries you can use 1-way TLS.   See [Easy wallet-less connections to Oracle Autonomous Databases in Python](https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/post/easy-way-to-connect-python-applications-to-oracle-autonomous-databases).